# Python flask - is it possible to create a personal website using only python?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to web-sites field and I was wondering if you can make a simple personal website using only python (NO HTML, CSS, JS) and flask. I was searching a bit on the internet and didn't find any good examples.

Is it possible? And if it is any code examples?

I vould appreciate if you have any suggestions or exaples.

Here is what I want my website to look like(it doesn't need to have this many functions): https://palletsprojects.com/

Comment: I don't think I understand your goal here. What do you want the pages to look like? How do you expect to configure how they look if you don't want to use the core technologies that do that? Maybe what you actually want is a static site generator like Jekyll

Comment: I vould like somenthing simmilar to this: https://www.techwithtim.net/ (but without that many functions. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think that is possible just using flask. I would suggest looking into static site generators. Here are some static site themes for Jekyll. You can probably find one that looks similar to that site and configure your content just using markdown and yaml files with little to no code https://jekyllthemes.io/free

Comment: But i want to make it on my own. Like a side project

Comment: The pallets website you linked is created with Lektor, a static CMS. Lektor will be more difficult to use than Jekyll but is more flexible https://www.getlektor.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Flask can be used for making realy simple websites with only basic text on them. But if you want a more developed website with more functions and a nicer desing you need to use html and css, and than you can use flask and python to implement 'logic' to them.

Here is a python flask tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZwr5Tvyxo

Answer (score 2):

You can but it's not going to look anything even remotely close to the URL you provided. You are going to need to have at least a little HTML to get your site even remotely close to graphically pleasing. However, I have recently discovered a new framework for web apps which is almost exclusively python. It's called [Pynecone](https://pynecone.io/). I hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

## Pynecone

Before 2023, I have no good answer to this question.
But today, **pynecone** is the answer for yours.
pynecone can let people write full-stack python code
without HTML and CSS.
(When I post this article, it is 2023/03)

There are four basic resources that can help you
understand what it is quickly.

### Working examples of pynecone

There are some working examples here.
https://pynecone.app/docs/gallery
All examples here are written in python.

### View of application developer

This video is helpful
for the application/web programmer to understand what it is.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ur4fCNMPp0I

### System view of pynecone

If you want to know what happened inside of the pynecone, the following video is helpful.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47BL6WLZJ1g

### pynecone web application => iOS/Android App

pynecone is very good tool for a python programmer to develop WebApp.

Furthermore, if you want to convert WebApp into iOS/Android App,
then you can use Capacitor to do it.
There is also a good article to introduce how to do it.
https://itnext.io/how-to-build-android-and-ios-apps-with-pynecone-6d2097a7610d

#### More resources

official documents of pynecone
https://pynecone.app/docs/getting-started/introduction
source code of pynecone
https://github.com/pynecone-io/pynecone

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Flask can be used to make your own personal website.

Making it with only Python and no HTML or CSS or client-side JS... no.

I guess you could use React with Python to evade HTML files, but you would still require CSS to make it look good.

Keep in mind, Flask is meant for small learning projects, and cannot handle large projects. If you want to make large projects, I recommend you try out [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com) ;)